# How to specify priority for custom rules in vee-validate?

Tags: validation, vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

Is there any way to specify a priority of rules in vee-validate? I have multiple rules attached to a field, like: **regex, custom_require_if, max** etc. When validating the empty field, it shows the error message for **regex** rule. But I want it to show the error message for **custom_require_if** rule. Is there any way to give **custom_require_if** rule more priority over **regex** rule?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the order of the rule declared, from `regex, custom_require_if, max` to `custom_require_if, regex, max`

It applies each rule you declared by following the order of the declaration, it works like an if full of "or" declarations.
The validation then fails upon the first rule not satisfied and return the corresponding error message